# Combining Bitmap on Android

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I want to combine two bitmap together. However, it can not combine 2 image that exceed 1600X1200.Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Someone tells me that it can enlarge the used memory of the apps.
Here's the error log

```
> 10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:423)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:374)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at com.org.testing.TestingActivity.crop(TestingActivity.java:102)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at com.org.testing.TestingActivity.access$0(TestingActivity.java:97)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at com.org.testing.TestingActivity$2.onClick(TestingActivity.java:54)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2428)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8939)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4668)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
10-26 12:07:16.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3221):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: why dont you decrease the size of the bitmap by using Bitmap.createScaledbitmap().

Answer (score 1):

You have three options :

1. Scale down the image. There is a 16 MB heap restriction
2. Use the ndk to do this, where this restriction does not apply
3. Do it server side.

Comment: Does there any method exist for breaking down the heap restriction?